# how would i get this program to print random numbers in the two dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I would like some advice on taking away the numbers I manually inserted and adding random numbers?
And if its possible to print random decimal numbers? looking for some advice or maybe a site that could help with two dimensional arrays don't really get them that well.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimensions
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      final int ROW = 3;
      final int COLUMN = 4;
      double scores[ ][ ] = { {66.7,77.8,88.9,55.6},
                              {88.4,82.1,99.4,85.4},
                              {55.6,66.6,77.6,69.4}
                            };


       System.out.print("  ");
       for (int heading = 0; heading < scores[0].length; heading++)
         System.out.printf("%4d ",heading + 1);
       System.out.println();
       for (int row = 0; row < scores.length; row++)
       {
         System.out.printf("%d  ",row+1);
         for (int column = 0; column < scores[row].length; column++)
           System.out.printf("%4.1f ", scores[row][column]);
         System.out.println();
       }
       for (int row = 0; row < ROW; row++)
       {
          double average = 0;
          for (int column = 0; column < COLUMN; column++)
             average += scores[row][column];
          System.out.printf("Average scores for row %d is %.2f\n",
                             (row + 1), (average / COLUMN));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean, pick a random decimal number in the 2D array, and print it out?

Comment: yes like you enter row 3 column 2 and it prints out what random number is in that place. my professor gave really bad examples and didn't focus on arrays at all so im really lost this was the best I could do lol

Comment: I have updated the answer to include 'allowing the user to select a specific row/column' as an example.

Comment: that's amazing I just saw lol thank you very much

Comment: ya sure how do I do accept lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, how about something like this?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomDecimalValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int ROW = 3;
        final int COLUMN = 4;
        double scores[][] = new double[ROW][COLUMN];

        Random randGenerator = new Random();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Initialize 2D array with appropriate random decimal values
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
                scores[i][j] = (randGenerator.nextDouble() * 99.0) + 1.0;
            }
        }

        // Print out array values
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4.1f ", scores[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        int randomRow = randGenerator.nextInt(ROW);
        int randomCol = randGenerator.nextInt(COLUMN);

        // Get a random decimal value from the 2D array
        System.out.println("\nRandom decimal value: ");
        System.out.printf("%-5.1f%n", scores[randomRow][randomCol]);

        // Prints out random decimal value from selected row/column
        System.out.printf("%nEnter a row number (1-%d): ", ROW);
        int selectedRow = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Enter a column number (1-%d): ", COLUMN);
        int selectedCol = sc.nextInt();

        if((selectedRow >= 1 && selectedRow <= ROW) &&
                (selectedCol >= 1 && selectedCol <= COLUMN))
        {
            System.out.printf("%nRandom decimal value at Row %d, Column %d: ",
                    selectedRow, selectedCol);
            System.out.printf("%4.1f%n",
                    scores[selectedRow - 1][selectedCol - 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid row/column values");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
47.5 25.7 72.9  4.7 
95.8 88.9 49.7 43.7 
66.5 10.1 93.9 41.6 

Random decimal value: 
72.9 

Enter a row number (1-3): 1
Enter a column number (1-4): 2

Random decimal value at Row 1, Column 2: 25.7
```

Comment: how would you make it so its not in decimals just for a future reference?

Comment: Declare a 2D array of your desired type, and change this part: `scores[i][j] = (randGenerator.nextDouble() * 99.0) + 1.0;`

Comment: thanks for the link and by change you mean put 99 instead of 99.0

Comment: No, by change, I mean you can use something such as `randGenerator.nextInt()` if you wish to get random integers instead.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean haha Im a very novice programmer professor didn't focus on random numbers or arrays

Comment: I got it to work haha I was reading what you wrote but wasn't actually reading it I kind of confused my self just looked back at it and fixed it thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

first instantiate a random object `Random generator = new Random();` then fill your array as below `double scores[ ][ ] = { {generator.nextInt(100),generator.nextInt(100),generator.nextInt(100),generator.nextInt(100)},
                              {generator.nextInt(100),generator.nextInt(100),generator.nextInt(100),generator.nextInt(100)},
                              {generator.nextInt(100),generator.nextInt(100),generator.nextInt(100),generator.nextInt(100)}
                            };` Note - you can change the bound i.e.100 as required and modify your code to handle int instead of double if you want to print decimals.